Where can I ask questions about a problem with using Firefox?
I have a problem with using the Firefox web browser and I'm not sure where to ask the question on the Stack Exchange network.
What site on the Stack Exchange Network is appropriate for questions about Firefox?

Questions about Firefox, along with questions about other browsers, operating systems, and more, are on-topic at Super User. At this time of writing, their firefox tag has over 8,700 questions, so be sure to look around at existing questions to see if your question has already been asked. If it hasn't, be sure to include any relevant information (such as possibly operating system, browser version, etc.) and ask your question. Good luck!
